# Print detail record on next page, although there is room on previous page

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have following problem.
I have main report with subreport. Subreport has detail band with group header and footer, with keepTogether = true. Each detail can have different number of rows.
Then I run the reports and on first page of result PDF there is:

- Detail record nr. 1
- Detail record nr. 2
- White space

On next page there is

- Detail record nr. 3

But detail 3 record has so height, that it could be printed on first page as:

- Detail record nr. 1
- Detail record nr. 2
- Detail record nr. 3

with no records on next page. But it is not so. Why ? Maybe there is any explanation for it, could you help me ? When I set page height longer then A4 paper size, there are all three records on first page. Depend it on height of subreport, as it is designed ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding your english. Please correct me if I've misinterpreted.  You're wondering why it's bleeding over to the next page when there's room on the previous page?

Comment: yes, right :-) sorry for english.

Comment: My guess is that you either have "page break" embedded in the subreports or the subreport hegiht is too big. Try playing around with those.

Comment: Can you post your JRXML so we can take a look?